# Sass expressions values precision difference

Tags: css, sass, materialize

This is from materialize.css source file `_grid.scss`

```
  $i: 1;
  @while $i <= $num-cols {
    $perc: unquote((100 / ($num-cols / $i)) + "%");
    &.m#{$i} {
      width: $perc;
      margin-left: 0;
    }
    $i: $i + 1;
  }
```

This is part of scss file that creates column grid styles.
When I've tried to replace it with (loop is the same, only body changed):

```
  &.offset-m#{$i} {
    margin-left: 100% / ($num-cols / $i);
  }
```

The result values were different in precision. (Took the values from couple of result classes).

Original: `width: 8.33333%;` new: `8.3333333333%;`

Original: `width: 16.66667%;` new: `16.6666666667%;`

1. Why is there a difference between Sass "inline" expression and $perc variable?
2. Is there any actual difference for browser? Maybe faster rendering? Did  materialize.css do it for a reason?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on Sassmeister with any version they offer or my own local Sass.  Even when I crank up the precision, the output is always the same for both examples.

Comment: @cimmanon I did it with cloned materialize.css `npm install`, `grunt monitor` my sass version `Sass 3.4.14 (Selective Steve)`

Comment: Unless materialize is providing their own custom build of Sass, the output you're claiming isn't possible (try for yourself: http://sassmeister.com/)

Comment: @BrianTompsett Stop making trivial edits that do nothing to improve the question.  Changing "Did guys from materialize.css did it for a reason?" to "Did materialize.css do it for a reason" is not a significant enough change to warrant bumping an old question.

Comment: @cimmanon Noted, thanks. Been editing new questions. That one must have slipped in by error.